# Search results by page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to search results in my Wordpress site. It gives posts information. But I want search results by pages.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'post' , 'search') ?>
<?php endwhile; else : ?>
```

This is default code given in search.php

And I added one code before above code for this operation.

```
 <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type'=> 'page',
            'order'    => 'ASC'
        );
        query_posts( $args );
    ?>
```

But it gives random results, and it doesn't go to the next page.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) filter to alter your search query. Add the following to your `functions.php`

```
function search_filter($query) {
  if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
      $query->set('post_type', 'page');
    }
  }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','search_filter');
```

Just for extra info, **NEVER EVER** use [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) to construct a custom query. In most cases, pagination fails as in your case, it is also resource intensive, therefore slow, and it alters the main main query

> **Note**: This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter the main query. query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts pagination).

If you can't use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query, and you have to use a custom query, use `WP_Query` or `get_posts` instead.

For additional reading, check out [my answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545) on [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/155956/31545)